# What is the best way to search case insensitive text using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

The first column of row are email addresses. I send that value to a search bar and click search and then I wait until the search results come through. Then I have this following if statement to search if that email address popped up in the results.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to make the search case insensitive. So that if I send 'test@email.com' and it finds 'tEsT@EMAIL.com' it will return true.

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[contains(text(), '" + row[1] + "')] | //*[@value='" + row[1] + "'])"):
    foundEmails += 1
    print("Found Email: " + row[1])
```

Comment: have you tried using regex? And can you explain why you need this? As for me it is not clear what the purpose is to search for capital-case-sensitive email addresses, as for email it does not matter if it is in capital or not.

Comment: The additional code creates a new account if it can't find a matching e-mail address. But then if that proceeds I'll encounter an error since that e-mail already exist just with different upper and lower case. I am not sure how to use regex in this context. I've tried to use

translate('blabla', 'abc', ABC) and lower-case()

but I can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution to my problem, for some reason upper-case and lower-case don't work, so I have to use translate()

```
     if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(translate(text(), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", '
             '"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), "{0}")]'.format(row[1].lower())):
```

Answer (score 1):

[matches()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) is an XPATH 2.0 function that allows for case-insensitive regex matching.

One of the flags is `i` for case-insensitive matching.

You can use following `XPATH` with the `matches()` function with the case-insensitive flag:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[matches(text(), '" + row[1] + "','i')] | //*[matches(@value,'" + row[1] + "','i')])"):
    foundEmails += 1
    print("Found Email: " + row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the text to lowercase first so that it can be matched:

```
     if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[contains(text(), '" + row[1] + "')] | //* 
                [@value='" + row[1] + "'])"):
            row[1] = row[1].lower() #assuming that this is the outputname, as you print this
            foundEmails += 1
            print("Found Email: " + row[1])
```

Comment: I don't want row[1] to be lower, it is already lower. I want whatever is doing the searching to be all lowercase.